# Passing value from Parent component to child component for ngForm in angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular, ngrx

I want to pass input value from Parent component () to 
child component ().(I tried with @input but its not working. I think I am making some mistake?)

parent component :

```
<value>
<search [vin]="vin"></search><-- child componnent 
<input class="in" type="text" pInputText [ngFormControl]="finVin" [ng-model]="vin"/>
</value>
class demo{
@Input() private vin:string;
}
```

child component :

```
 <search>
    <div class="lbl">
        {{vin}}

    </div>
    </search>
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: `[ng-model]` is changed to `[ngModel]`.

```
<value>
   <search [vin]="vin"></search><-- child componnent 
   <input class="in" type="text" pInputText [ngFormControl]="finVin" [ngModel]="vin"/>
</value>

class demo{
   vin="Angular2";
}
```

---

```
<search>
    <div class="lbl">
        {{vin}}

    </div>
</search>


export class search{
     @Input() private vin:string;

     ngOnChanges(...args:any[]){
           //console.log(args[0].vin); //for previous and current value.
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have it the wrong way round.
The `@Input` annotation is needed in the child component, so Angular 2 knows you're passing something into it.

So remove the `@Input` in your parent component and add it to your child component:

```
class search {
    @Input() private vin:string;
}
```